# Перебор вариантов с данными из массива в Pascal

Tags: pascalabc.net

У меня есть массив допустим из букв от `a` до `c`. Как сделать чтобы выводились все возможные комбинации с этими буквами, в начале только `a, b, c`, потом `aa,ab,ac,ba,bb` и т.д. Пока не переберутся все значения из массива. С перебором проблем нет, но как сделать чтобы после окончания перебора например 2 букв, она добавила еще одну.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что не можете после `с` перейти к `aa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для перебора всех подмножеств используйте двоичный перебор.
Алгоритм:

> Пусть длина массива/множества = `l`
>     Перебираем все числа от `0` до `2^l - 1` 
>     Для каждого из двоичных представлений этих чисел "1" на i-ой позиции означает наличие i-ого элемента множества в подмножестве. Соответственно "0" означает отсутствие этого элемента в подмножестве.

Короче говоря, код:

```
Function bin(n: integer;): string; // Функция перевода в двоичную с.с.
... 

Function step(a, n: integer;): longint; // Функция возведения в степень
...

Var ...;
Begin
...
//a - массив подмножества которого надо найти
For i:=0 to step(2, l) - 1 do
begin
  binar:= bin(i);
  for j:=1 to l do if binar[j] = '1' then write(a[j]);
  writeln;
end;
...
End.
```

Пример: 
 a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 i = 5
 bin(i) = '101'
 подмножество - ('a', 'c')
 вывод в консоль - ac
 Здесь идем с начала строки:
 1-ый элемент - единица, выведем 1-ый элемент массива `a`. 
 2-ой элемент - ноль, ничего не выводим. 
 3-ий элемент - единица, выведем 3-ий элемент массива `a`.